# For which values of a is the linear operator injective and surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem:**

1. Find all values which the resulting linear system has (a) no solution, (b) a unique solution, and (c) infinitely many solutions.
   \begin{cases} 
         x+y-z=2\\
         x+2y+z=3\\
         x+y+(a^2-5)z=a\\
      \end{cases}
2. Find all the values of a for which the linear application
   $$T(x,y,z)=(x+y-z,x+2y+z,z+y+(a^2-5)z)$$
   is injective and subjective.

First we will rewrite the system of equations above to be in the form of a matrix.

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & a^2-5 & a \\
\end{array}

After some addition and subtraction of rows, we have the following matrix:

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & -1 & -2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 4-a^2 & 2-a \\
\end{array}

**Part 1a:** We get no solution if we have the (3,3) entry equal to zero and the (3,4) entry not equal to zero. Therefore $a^2-4=0$ and $2-a \neq 0$, thus $a=-2$.

**Part 1b:** We get a unique solutions as long as neither the (3,3) entry nor the (3,4) entry are zero. Therefore $a \neq \pm 2$.

**Part 1c:** We get infinitely many solutions if both the (3,3) and (3,4) entries are zero. Therefore $a=2$.

**Part 2:**

**Important Definitions:**

- A linear operation T is called injective if $x=0$ whenever $Tx=0$. (i.e. If $Tx=0$ then $x=0$.)
- It is called surjective if the range of T, defined $range(T)=\{Tx:x\in \nu\}=T\nu$, is equal to the entire vector space W.

First we will find for what values of a for which $Tu=0$, where u is a vector. Hence we can write the linear operator in the form of the following matrix:

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & a^2-5 & 0 \\
\end{array}

After some addition and subtraction of rows, we have the following matrix:

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4-a^2 & 0 \\
\end{array}

Hence we have the following equations, from the matrix:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x+y-z & =0 \\
y+2z &=0 \\
(4-a^2)z & =0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

We can see that we can get the vector $u=(x,y,z)$ is the zero vector for all a's except when $a= \pm 2$.

**How do I approach the surjective portion?**

Comment: Looking at your work, I'd say your final answer for 1a should be $a=-2$.

Comment: @paw88789 Thank you for noticing the typo

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For $T$ to be surjective, the system $Tx=v$ must be solvable for all vectors $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$.  Thus you could look at the system
$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
x+2y+z & =v_1 \\
x+2y+z &=v_2 \\
x+y+(a^2-5)z & =v_3 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}$$
and try to decide under what conditions on $a$ you would get a solution no matter what are the values of $v_1, v_2,v_3$.

There are other methods to approach this problem, depending on what techniques you have available.